# Separating Strings Contained in data.frame and creating a new associated value based on splits

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a large set of data in which some rows contain multiple counties separated by commas. I have been making attempts to make them into separate rows with the value of money associated with the string divided by the number of counties in the string.  In addition to having strings of counties, there are statewide values that must be split across each county in the state. For the sake of an easily replicable example we will have to assume Maryland has only three counties. For a replicable example I will paste some code below:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(State = 
c("Maryland","Maryland","Maryland","Washington","Arizona","California"),
County = c("Baltimore,Montgomery,Frederick","Statewide","Baltimore, 
Carrol","Douglas","Washington","San Bernadino,Orange"),Spending = 
c(15000,20000,10000,5000,2000,34000))
> print(df1)
       State                         County Spending
1   Maryland Baltimore,Montgomery,Frederick    15000
2   Maryland                      Statewide    20000
3   Maryland              Baltimore, Carrol    10000
4 Washington                        Douglas     5000
5    Arizona                     Washington     2000
6 California           San Bernadino,Orange    34000
```

---

I would like the output to look like the data.frame printed below.

```
> df2 <- data.frame(State = c("Maryland","Maryland","Maryland","Maryland",
"Washington","Arizona","California","California"),County = 
c("Baltimore","Montgomery","Frederick","Carrol","Douglas",
"Washington","San Bernadino","Orange"),
Spending = c(15000,10000,10000,10000,5000,2000,17000,17000))
> print(df2)
       State        County Spending
1   Maryland     Baltimore    15000
2   Maryland    Montgomery    10000
3   Maryland     Frederick    10000
4   Maryland        Carrol    10000
5 Washington       Douglas     5000
6    Arizona    Washington     2000
7 California San Bernadino    17000
8 California        Orange    17000
```

The trickery is located in the fact that not all rows have the county strings and the statewide value must be based on the number of counties contained within the state.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet that failed?  You might clean up your examples; your first doesn't run as given and I think the number in the output example don't line up with your input example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the freedom to modify your dataframe slightly because it was not working (as the commenter stated). Is this what you're looking for?

```
df1 <- data.frame(State = 
                c("Maryland","Maryland","Washington","Arizona","California"),County = 
                c("Baltimore,Montgomery,Frederick","Statewide","Douglas","Washington","San Bernadino,Orange"),Spending = c(15000, 15000,6000,2000,34000))

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)


df1 %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% # group by state
  mutate(Total_Spending = sum(Spending)) %>% # calculate total spending
  filter(County != "Statewide") %>% # delete rows for statewide as they don't count as a county
  separate_rows(County, sep = ",") %>% # expand rows
  mutate(Spending_PC = Total_Spending / n()) # calculate spending per county
```

**Edit** based on the new info by the OP:

I take a more or less five-step approach:

1. take out the statewide rows to deal with them later
2. with the rest, count the number of counties in each row (by looking at the number of commas in County) and divide the Spending amount accordingly.
3. expand the rows
4. group by county and summarize the Spendings for it
5. Join the statewide information and distribute it to the counties (adjusted for the number of counties in the state)

   ```
   statewide <- df1 %>% 
     filter(County == "Statewide") %>% 
     select(-County, Spending_State = Spending)

   df1 %>% 
     filter(County != "Statewide") %>%  # drop the statewide rows 
     # divide the spending of each row by the number of counties (as counted by "," + 1)
     mutate(Spending_div = Spending / (str_count(County, ",") + 1)) %>% 
     separate_rows(County, sep = ",") %>% # expand rows
     # calculate spending per county (account for multiple rows per county)
     group_by(State, County) %>% 
     summarize(Spending_County = sum(Spending_div)) %>%  
     # join the statewide spending 
     left_join(statewide) %>% 
     replace_na(list(Spending_State = 0)) %>% # replace non matched with 0 
     # calculate final value 
     group_by(State) %>% # group to get number of counties in each state to distribute the Spending_State
     mutate(Spending_County = Spending_County + (Spending_State / n()))
   ```

There is also a way to do it without extracting the statewide info first but this is even more messy and not so "tidy" imho.

Comment: I appologize about the sample i had given.  I have edited the data frame to show the complexity involved with the spending value.  Some counties are repeated and put into different strings, so the total spending for each county is not just split evenly across the state.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the problem now. Now, your dataset looks pretty tidy already. Or is this the desired result? Maybe could you show us what you want to achieve and elaborate a bit on "some counties are repeated and put into different strings" as I don't see that in the example data.

Comment: the df2 is the desired output I am trying to achieve. When I say that counties can appear in multiple rows I am referring to the inclusion of baltimore in rows 1 and 3. This affects the desired output greatly because the output must include the proportion of the spending from both rows. So, Baltimore would have a final spending of 15000 because it has a proportion equivelant to 5000 in 3 seperate rows (inclusion of the statewide row based on state only containing counties present in the current data.frame)

Comment: does my edit work? at least it gives out the right result for your example dataset and it should be generalizable given some conditions (i.e. "Statewide" is never put together in a row with counties).

Comment: There is actually some small problem with joining the statewide back in which I am attempting to look into now. I believe it is having issue with it being previously taken out in the initial filter.

Comment: what is the issue exactly?

Comment: It is tossing me an error in this line `left_join(Statewide) %>% ` and the error is `Error in tbl_vars(y) : object 'Statewide' not found` I had thought it was because your script had a lowercase s when it first gave the error and then tried uppercase and it also did not accept it.

Comment: werid, i cannot replicate this. This might sound really trivial, but are you sure you executed the `statewide <- ` part first? The name inside `left_join` must be the same as what you assigned the first block to.

Comment: trivial but not wrong i completely missed running that because it was inside a larger section of code. Thank you very much for the assistance! Greatly appreciated.